# ItemListener not detecting JCombobox selection change and making necessary changes

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener, jcombobox, itemlistener

I'm working on a practice application and I'm new to JFrame.  I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing here.. I know I need to reference itemStateChanged somewhere, but I'm not sure where it would be most suitable.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class DebugFourteen3 extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
JComboBox pizzaBox = new JComboBox();
JLabel toppingList = new JLabel("Topping List");
JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Paulos's American Pie");
JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
int[] pizzaPrice = {7,10,10,8,8,8,8};
int totalPrice = 0;
String output;
int pizzaNum;
public DebugFourteen3()
{
   super("Pizza List");
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setLayout(flow);
   pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
   add(toppingList);
   pizzaBox.addItem("cheese");
   pizzaBox.addItem("sausage");
   pizzaBox.addItem("pepperoni");
   pizzaBox.addItem("onion");
   pizzaBox.addItem("green pepper");
   pizzaBox.addItem("green olive");
   pizzaBox.addItem("black olive");
   add(pizzaBox);
   add(aLabel);
}
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
   JFrame frame = new DebugFourteen3();
   frame.setSize(200, 150);
   frame.setVisible(true);
}


public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)
{
 Object source = list.getSource();
 if(source == pizzaBox)
 {
    int pizzaNum = pizzaBox.getSelectedIndex();
    totalPrice = pizzaPrice[pizzaNum];
    output = "Pizza Price $" + totalPrice;
    totPrice.setText(output);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`itemStateChanged` takes an `ItemEvent` arg, not an array

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)
```

Should be

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
```

Also, the correct way to add a listener to a `Combobox` and detect a selection change is to use an `ActionListener`.  You should leave out the `itemStateChanged()` and use this.

```
public class DebugFourteen3 extends JFrame implements {

    ...

    public DebugFourteen3()
    {
        ...
        pizzabox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int pizzaNum = pizzaBox.getSelectedIndex();
                totalPrice = pizzaPrice[pizzaNum];
                output = "Pizza Price $" + totalPrice;
                totPrice.setText(output); 
            }
        });
    }

    ...
}
```